# L.markerClusterGroup is not a function

Tags: wordpress, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm trying to use leaflet cluster markers. I created a template for a WP page.

First, I'm loading library and css :

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-/Nsx9X4HebavoBvEBuyp3I7od5tA0UzAxs+j83KgC8PU0kgB4XiK4Lfe4y4cgBtaRJQEIFCW+oC506aPT2L1zw==" crossorigin=""></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>
```

Then I create my map :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    lat = 47.468700;
    var lon = -0.558810;
    var macarte = null;
    var markerClusters;
    var markers = [];
    var iconBase = '';

    function initMap() {
        macarte = L.map('map').setView([lat, lon], 8);
        markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup();

       [•••]
</script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

But when I load my page, I always have this error :

```
L.markerClusterGroup is not a function
```

If I remove `markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup();` my map is loaded.

This same code works on another website.
I tried to replace my child theme with a blank theme, but the problem is always here.

Thanks for help.

Comment: are you sure that the markercluster library is loaded when you call `L.markerClusterGroup()`?

Comment: My JS and CSS are loaded before my initMap

Comment: Some debugging ideas - 1: check the network tab and make sure the urls you have to the markercluster js and css resources are correct, i.e. they're being loaded in the page as you expect. 2: check in the console if `markerClusterGroup` exists on the `L` object.

Comment: @SethLutske 1 : ressources are loaded on network tab.  : `markerClusterGroup` doesn't exist on `L` object

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

I use a plugin from french gouvernement to load local information and this one use leaflet...

Thanks all for your answers.